# How to Set List Items of a usercontrol in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, items

I create a User Control. this has a dependencypoperty by this type

```
List<CustomSubMenuItem>
```

and CustomSubMeuItem

```
class CustomSubMenuItem
{
public string Title {get;set;}
public Color BackColor {get;set;}
publiv Visibility ItemVisibility {get;set;}
public ICommand Command {get;set;}
}
```

in XAML i bind to the prperty in usuall. but i cant make this items in XAML, Like ContextMenu or ListBoxItems.

```
<MyControl>
<MyControl.Items>
<CustomSubMenuItem Title="First" Visibility="{Binding Model.firstvisibility}"/>
<CustomSubMenuItem Title="Second" Visibility="{Binding Model.secondvisibility}"/>
</MyControl.Items>
</MyControl>
```

but this kind has error,what can I do.

UPDATE:
Thanks,
I Reach to answer below. i did not define the namespace of class in the xaml. and the upper code is true when i add the **namespace:** before **CustomSubItemMenu**.

Comment: Doesn't Items="{Binding ItemCollectionName}" work ?

Comment: yes it is works. but i need to change some items in run time and need to bind to the inner properties. such as Visibility.

Comment: Mark my answer as correct if it was right answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Set your control datacontext to your list and then bind ItemsSource to it:

```
List<CustomSubMenuItem> MenuItems = new List<CustomSubMenuItem>();
MyControl.DataContext = MenuItems;
```

Then in XAML f.e:

```
  <MyControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <MyControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/></DataTemplate>
    </MyControl.ItemTemplate>
 </MyControl>
```

You can bind your Title and Color the way you want it.

UPDATE:

If you want to bind Visibility to one of your property, one way to do it is to have bool value in Model and bind it to visibility. Also you need a ValueConverter to set true value as visible and false as hidden.

First, add a namespace in window. Declare that namespace where your ValueConverter class is defined.

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:NamespaceHere"
```

XAML for binding visibility:

```
<MyControl Visibility="{Binding VisibilityValue, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
```

Then add ValueConverter to your :

```
<vm:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="converter" />
```

Lastly, you need to create the ValueConverter class, use mine as a example:

```
 public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool val = (bool)value;
        if(val)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
           return Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool val = (bool)value;
        if (val)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i am using MVVM Pattern and i need to bind for example Visibility of each item in the list to one property in my model. like when you make menuitem in xaml. you set title for each menuitem etc.

Comment: thanks, but i dont want to set visibility to my user-control. please tell me how you set visibility to a context-menu with 5 item, that 2 items should be collapsed at the beginning of project run.

Comment: Do you want the listitems to be List Items or what contextmenu are you talking about?

Comment: I Want to make my items in xaml not binding for example like context-menu

Comment: Then you just add this inside to <MyControl.Items></MyControl.Items> <MyControlItem Name="listitem name"></MyControlItem>

Answer (score 0):

Your CustomSubMenuItem should derive from MenuItem or at least from FrameworkElement, if you want to instantiate it in your VisualTree, which is where `<MyControl.Items>` is.

Alternatively, you can create your item-list as a StaticResource and then bind to this resource, like this (adjust namespaces of course) and if you need apply an ItemTemplate:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="menuItems" Type="{x:Type local:CustomSubMenuItem}" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:yourNamespace">
            <local:CustomSubMenuItem Property1="value1" Property2="value2" />
            <local:CustomSubMenuItem Property1="value3" />
    </x:Array>
<Window.Resources>

<MyControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource menuItems}">
     <MyControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" />
           </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```